# Django admin interface

Tags: django, admin

Is it possible to display in admin interface objects that related to the current user?
For example:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    to = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I have several admins and I want to display messages to the related admin. Thank you!

Comment: you want to show something depending of which user is logged in the admin interface?

Answer (score 4):

You can customize your admin site by putting a file named `admin.py` in your application directory, writing a `ModelAdmin` class for your model and overriding its [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset) method, like this:

```
class FeedbackModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('message',)

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(FeedbackModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(to=request.user)
```

Check the full [documentation of the Django admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/).